# How to label (x,y) data points in Gnuplot 4.2 with integer numbers

Tags: gnuplot

I have a text file with 2 columns of numbers corresponding to (x,y) coords.

```
4 1
4 5
1 1
1 5
2.5 3
```

How do I tell gnuplot to plot these points and label each point with its corresponding row #?  (Please keep in mind I'm going to apply this to a much larger file with 100 points, so I'm looking for a way to do it automagically, rather than have to create a 3rd column of data corresponding to row numbers).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `with labels` flag to the plot command.  By default this places the label instead of the point at the place where the point would be.  `with label` takes the `offset` flag (and any flag you can pass to `set label`) so you can have the label next to the point.  Here is an example script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

reset

set terminal pngcairo
set output 'test.png'

set xr [0:5]
set yr [0:6]

plot 'data.dat' pt 7, \
     'data.dat' using 1:2:($0+1) with labels offset 1 notitle
```

which produces this output:

[image]

Comment: The docs state:  `The font, color, rotation angle and other properties of the printed text
 may be specified as additional command options (see "set label")` (from `help style labels`) ... thats the best I can do as far as documentation is concerned.  Anyway, this is the correct way to do it I think.  +1