# Rotated datapoint labels in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, label

With regards to the answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14609537/2000581

How can I apply special formatting (e.g. rotate) to the labels ?

I can use

```
set label {tag} rotate by 45
```

to get a 45 degree rotated label. But plotting labels at datapoints, as given in the previously mentioned answer, has a different command format (... w labels u ...).

Perhaps a way to change the default label formatting ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whats wrong with appending `rotate by 45` to the `offset 1` part?:

Consider the file `test.txt`:

```
4 1
4 5
1 1
1 5
2.5 3
```

and the script:

```
set xr [0:5]
set yr [0:6]

plot 'test.txt' using 1:2:($0+1) with labels point pt 7 offset 1 rotate by 45 notitle
```

which gives a nice output image:

[image]