# Is it possible to read the value of a label in gnuplot from a file

Tags: gnuplot

Creating labels in gnulot is quite simple

```
set label "<value>" at <x,y> ...
```

But I want to read the value of a label in gnuplot from a file.

The lines in the file look this way:

```
...
400 300 8 0.200214 1.00193 7.42157 8.623714 86.06 13.94 1.26
800 600 1 0.2055 0.1938 34.9172 35.3165 98.86 1.14 1.00
800 600 2 0.2066 1.5514 21.1664 22.9244 92.33 7.67 1.54
800 600 4 0.2027 1.6316 14.9445 16.7788 89.06 10.94 2.10
800 600 8 0.242 1.8385 12.7261 14.8066 85.94 14.06 2.38
1024 768 1 0.2212 0.2217 55.1782 55.6211 99.20 0.80 1.00
...
```

I just need the values from the 10th column as labels.

Is it possible to realize something like this:

`set label from <inputfile> <column_of_inputfile> <row_of_inputfile> ...`

?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes, use the `labels` plotting style, see. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/15170696/2604213 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/14608900/2604213

Comment: Thanks a lot. With these sources, I was able to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

```
set title "800x600"

set xlabel "Nodes [#]\n"         
set ylabel "Speedup" offset 2
set xrange [-0.55:3.55]
set yrange [0:5]
set style data histograms         # plot boxes
set boxwidth 0.75                 # have a gap between the boxes

plot 'inputfile.csv' every ::9::12 using 10:xtic(3) title "800x600" lc rgb "grey",\
      '' every ::9::12 using :10:10 with labels center  offset 0,1 tc rgb "black"
```

The first plot line does in detail:

- **every ::9::12** => plot line 9-12 of the inputfile.
- **using 10:xtic(3)** => the value of column number 10 specifies the height of the data histograms. The value of column 3 is used for labeling the x axis.

The second plot line plots the content of column 10 of the lines 9-12 as label in center orientation above the data histograms.

The image shows the result.

[image: Gnuplot result with labels obove boxes. The values come from the input file]